# Python - Find percent change for previous 7-day period's average

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have time-series data in a dataframe. Is there any way to calculate for each day the percent change of that day's value from the average of the previous 7 days?

I have tried

```
df['Change'] = df['Column'].pct_change(periods=7)
```

However, this simply finds the difference between t and t-7 days. I need something like:

*For each value of Ti, find the average of the previous 7 days, and subtract from Ti*

Comment: do you mean to make this a ratio relative to the trailing mean, i.e.:  `new_value = (value - mean_7) / mean_7`, or just a difference, i.e. `new_value = value - mean_7`?

Comment: The first option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can for example use:

```py
s = df['Column']
n = 7
mean = s.rolling(n, closed='left').mean()
df['Change'] = (s - mean) / mean
```

**Note on `closed='left'`**

There was a [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/34315) prior to `pandas=1.2.0` that caused incorrect handling of `closed` for fixed windows. Make sure you have `pandas>=1.2.0`; for example, `pandas=1.1.3` will not give the result below.

As described in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html):

> `closed`: Make the interval closed on the ‘right’, ‘left’, ‘both’ or ‘neither’ endpoints. Defaults to ‘right’.

A simple way to understand is to try with some very simple data and a small window:

```py
a = pd.DataFrame(range(5), index=pd.date_range('2020', periods=5))
b = a.assign(
    sum_left=a.rolling(2, closed='left').sum(),
    sum_right=a.rolling(2, closed='right').sum(),
    sum_both=a.rolling(2, closed='both').sum(),
    sum_neither=a.rolling(2, closed='neither').sum(),
)

>>> b
            0  sum_left  sum_right  sum_both  sum_neither
2020-01-01  0       NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN
2020-01-02  1       NaN        1.0       1.0          NaN
2020-01-03  2       1.0        3.0       3.0          NaN
2020-01-04  3       3.0        5.0       6.0          NaN
2020-01-05  4       5.0        7.0       9.0          NaN
```

Comment: i've been searching online but haven't fully understood - what does the "closed" parameter control?

Comment: Additionally, is there any way not to include the value at *t* in the calculation of the mean? i.e. (t - mean(t-1...t-8))/ mean(t-1...t-8)

Comment: exaclty, that's what the `closed='left'` means: the "right" side (`t`) is not included in the window, only the "left" side (`t-7`).

Comment: tt = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,4,5,6,8,10,11,12,15,13,13,14,12,13,13,13,19,16,17,18,17,17,18]}); tt['CHANGE'] = tt.rolling(7, closed='left')['A'].mean()

Comment: for some reason, even with the "Left" close, the average is still including the current values

Comment: your line is incorrect (missing 7 and 9), and a rolling mean of 7 values makes it difficult to understand at first glance. Let me add a quick explanatory note in the answer.

Comment: the missing numbers are deliberate - I wanted to ensure the calculations of percent change would be accurate :)

Comment: I added a note on this in the edited answer. The `close='left'` for window width `w` definitely includes `i - w` and excludes `i` for the result at row `i`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231455/discussion-between-dror-m-and-pierre-d).